# Parse xml for text of every specific tag not working

Tags: python, xml, parsing, element

I am trying to gather every element `<sequence-number>` text into a list. Here is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from lxml import etree 

response = '''
<rpc-reply xmlns:nc="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0" xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0" message-id="urn:uuid:0d07cdf5-c8e5-45d9-89d1-92467ffd7fe4">
 <data>
  <ipv4-acl-and-prefix-list xmlns="http://cisco.com/ns/yang/Cisco-IOS-XR-ipv4-acl-cfg">
   <accesses>
    <access>
     <access-list-name>TESTTEST</access-list-name>
     <access-list-entries>
      <access-list-entry>
       <sequence-number>1</sequence-number>
       <remark>TEST</remark>
       <sequence-str>1</sequence-str>
      </access-list-entry>
      <access-list-entry>
       <sequence-number>10</sequence-number>
       <grant>permit</grant>
       <source-network>
        <source-address>10.10.5.0</source-address>
        <source-wild-card-bits>0.0.0.255</source-wild-card-bits>
       </source-network>
       <next-hop>
        <next-hop-type>regular-next-hop</next-hop-type>
        <next-hop-1>
         <next-hop>10.10.5.2</next-hop>
         <vrf-name>SANE</vrf-name>
        </next-hop-1>
       </next-hop>
       <sequence-str>10</sequence-str>
      </access-list-entry>
      <access-list-entry>
       <sequence-number>20</sequence-number>
       <grant>permit</grant>
       <source-network>
        <source-address>10.10.6.0</source-address>
        <source-wild-card-bits>0.0.0.255</source-wild-card-bits>
       </source-network>
       <next-hop>
        <next-hop-type>regular-next-hop</next-hop-type>
        <next-hop-1>
         <next-hop>10.10.6.2</next-hop>
         <vrf-name>VRFNAME</vrf-name>
        </next-hop-1>
       </next-hop>
       <sequence-str>20</sequence-str>
      </access-list-entry>
     </access-list-entries>
    </access>
   </accesses>
  </ipv4-acl-and-prefix-list>
 </data>
</rpc-reply>
'''
q = etree.fromstring(response)
print(q.findall('.//sequence-number'))
```

But get nothing for output. I have tried the following statements too with no luck:

```
print(q.findall('./sequence-number/'))
print(q.findall('sequence-number/'))
print(q.findall('.//sequence-number/'))
print(q.findall('sequence-number'))
```

How can I gather this data?

Comment: did you try lxml ?

Comment: @Sudheej, yes I imported it, but I am not sure I know how to use it. Can you share recommendations on how to use it? My code gives no output.

Comment: A default Namespace has to be taken into account `xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0"` or use `//*[local-name()="sequence-number"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, xml namespaces should be considered. The most simple way to handle them would be using the `xpath` function instead of `findall` along with the slight modification of the search expression:

```
print(q.xpath(".//*[local-name()='sequence-number']"))
```

Here expression `.//*[local-name()='sequence-number']`contains the wildcard `*` with the predicate `[local-name()='sequence-number']`. It means that every child element should be select having local name (without namespace consideration) equal to "sequence-number".

Another approach would be creation of a namespace map and passing it to the `findall` function:

```
ns = {"ns":"http://cisco.com/ns/yang/Cisco-IOS-XR-ipv4-acl-cfg"}
print(q.findall(".//ns:sequence-number", ns))
```

Comment: This worked. It worked in the sense that I did not need to remove the name spaces.

Comment: However, `urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0` as a name space does not work. Why is that?

Comment: In your example there are two namespaces like that: `xmlns:nc="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0"` and `xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0"`. Which one doesn't work and in what way?